# Density weighted Law of Large Numbers argument for the convergence of an expectation approximation

Tags: probability, density-function, monte-carlo, weights, law-of-large-numbers

Given a set of IID samples $X = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ assumed to be from the density $p(\cdot)$, and the function $h:\mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$, its expectation can be approximated as
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int h(x)p(x)dx \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nh(x_i) $$
as usual. However, I have recently come across this approximation

$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)] =  \int p(x)h(x)dx \approx \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n p(x_i)}\sum_{i=1}^np(x_i)h(x_i)$$

in the paper "[Density-Weighted Nyström Method for Computing Large Kernel Eigensystems](https://scholar.archive.org/work/pywsdz5qtnd2db65skrhssunxi)" by Kai Zhang and James T. Kwok. *Neural Computation* 21, 121–146 (2009).

I can't understand how this approximation makes sense, as for a start we have

$$\mathbb{E}[p(X)h(X)] = \int h(x)p(x)^2dx$$
which is the wrong integral to be targeting.

They don't justify their approximation, it is just stated and is shown to work empirically in their context. I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you? Both are $\sum_i w_i h(x_i)$ where in the first case $w_i = 1/n$ and in the second case the weights are not uniform $w_i = p_i/\sum_j p_j$, but as in the first case, they sum to $1$.

Comment: This is a useful framing of it thank you. I suppose I'm confused why this weighting would actually allow that sum to converge to the correct expectation. I though that the usual weighted LLN arguments can't be used here as the weights are random variables themselves now?

Comment: I understand that if we can treat them as non-random we have unbiasedness as 
$$\mathbb{E}[\sum_i w_i h(X_i)] =\mathbb{E}[h(X)] $$ but I suppose my question is that are the $w_i$'s themselves not random variables here, and they wouldn't be independent from the $h(X_i)$'s?